# How to capture photo from recyclerView in Android - Kotlin language

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-camera

I have simple task. In recyclerView when I click on any button I would like to start camera, take photo and then capture this photo. However I'm not able to find any solution for this. What I tried in RecyclerAdapter.kt:

```
  inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firma_textView1)

        init {
            textView1.setOnClickListener {
                capturePhoto(context, activity)
            }
        }
    }

    fun capturePhoto(context: Context, activity: Activity) {
        if (getCameraPermission(context)) {
            val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            startActivityForResult(activity, cameraIntent, FirstFragment.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE, null)
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), FirstFragment.CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun getCameraPermission (context: Context):Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
```

With this code I could start camera, take picture, but in RecyclerAdapter there is no way how to capture taken image.

Normal way how to capture image in Fragment is this:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        var buttonCapturePhoto = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        buttonCapturePhoto.setOnClickListener {
            capturePhoto()
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            print("photo captured")
        }
    }

    private fun capturePhoto() {
        if (getCameraPermission(requireContext())) {
            val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        }
    }

    private fun getCameraPermission (context: Context):Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
```

I also found this article at Android Developer page - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

They suggest to create class MyLifecycleObserver and use it in Fragment, but I'm not able to use this code in RecycleAdapter

```
lateinit var observer : MyLifecycleObserver

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...

        observer = MyLifecycleObserver(requireActivity().activityResultRegistry)
        lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
    }
```

I get error at `activityResultRegistry` and at `lifecycle`

I also created for testing this git repository: https://github.com/Katzzer/recyclerViewPhotoCaptureKotlinAndroid

Comment: Don't try to do it in your adapter. Your activity result listener should update the corresponding item in the backing list of the adapter and then pass the new list to the adapter (or notify it of which item number has changed). The adapter should just be for adapting data to views and calling back to the Activity or Fragment when input is received.

Comment: Tenfour04: But I need to know what button in recyclerView was pressed, I want to get the image and set it to recyclerView

Comment: So each recycler view list item has a button, and when it's clicked, you want the photo to appear in that line item?

Comment: Yea something like that. It is for much greater project but I made this example as simple as possible.

Comment: How about passing your click event to the fragment/activity ?? you can use custom interface `OnItemClickListener` or whatever you call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass your click event to fragment/activity

1. Create custom `interface` inside your adapter
2. Pass it into adapter constructor

```
// pass listener into constructor
class RecyclerAdapter(
  val list:List<YourItemClass>,
  val listener: OnItemClickListener) : ... {
  
  // create a custom listener
  interface OnItemClickListener{
    fun onItemClick(view:View, position:Int)
   }
  
  inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        // create function bind instead of using init block
        fun bind(item:YourItemClass){
            val textView1: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firma_textView1)
            // if you want to change image in your ImageView , you could also pass 
            // your ImageView too
            val imgView: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView)
            textView1.setOnClickListener { view ->
                // this is just an example , but you get the idea

                // listen click event and pass view and position
                listener.onItemClick(view, adapterPosition)
                // or
                listener.onItemClick(imgView, adapterPosition)
            }
        }
    }

   ...
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = list[position]
        // bind here
        holder.bind(item)
    }
  ...
}
```

3. Initialized your adapter in `Fragment/Activity`
4. Listen to click event in `Fragment/Activity`

```
...
adapter = RecyclerAdapter(list, object : RecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
   override fun onItemClick(view:View, position:Int){
     // Listen your click event here
     capturePhoto().also { result ->
         // do something

         // dont forget to call notifyItem if you want to update an item in 
         // RecyclerView
         adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)
      }
   }
}
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
...
```

5. Create your `capturePhoto` function in `Fragment\Activity`